# Does Bruce Springsteen ever called Steve Van Zandt his "consiglieri"?

Tags: reference-request, bruce-springsteen

This [review](https://sopranosautopsy.com/season-6-part-i/mayham-6-03/) of the TV show *The Sopranos* says that:

> Bruce Springsteen has even referred to Van Zandt as his consiglieri.

Steve Van Zandt is Bruce Springsteen guitarist and he also plays the character Silvio Dante who is Tony Soprano's *consiglieri* in the show.

Searching with google always refer to the show and the fact that Steve is actor/guitarist so I didn't find any source of this alleged Bruce Springsteen statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any direct quote from Springsteen, but Van Zandt does refer to himself that way in an interview with Billboard Magazine:

> My relationship with Bruce was the same relationship that Silvio had with Tony Soprano. Silvio was not afraid of Tony. Bruce and I grew up together, so I’m never going to be afraid of him. You want a buffer in between the leader and the day-to-day problems that a band has. [Longtime Springsteen tour director] George Travis fulfills that role for Bruce now, but in the old days, I was that guy. I was a very good *consigliere*.
>   https://www.billboard.com/articles/columns/rock/7793162/steven-van-zandt-relationship-bruce-springsteen-solo-album-soulfire

There's also [any number of references](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&ei=046dWqi2Isr2swXmgJP4CQ&q=Steve+Van+Zandt+consiglieri+-Sopranos+-Soprano&oq=Steve+Van+Zandt+consiglieri+-Sopranos+-Soprano&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3057.5753.0.6086.11.10.1.0.0.0.115.750.9j1.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.h264fTOwPqE) to Van Zandt as the *consigliere* of the E Street Band, independent of the show (although likely influenced by it).